# How do I recall Gooigi in co-op mode?

Tags: luigis-mansion-3

Co-op mode in Luigi's Mansion 3 is a lot of fun, but for one problem: When Gooigi goes out exploring territory where Luigi can't follow, sometimes it's impossible for him to come back by normal means, e.g. when he falls down a drain.

In single player mode, I can just press the right stick button on my controller twice to recall Gooigi to Luigi's position. However, this doesn't seem to work in co-op mode.

So far the only way I've found to continue playing is to temporarily turn off co-op mode when Gooigi gets stuck, recall him in single player mode, and turn co-op back on. This is quite a hassle, since it requires re-connecting the controllers and is overall a lot of steps.

Is there any way in co-op mode to recall Gooigi back to Luigi's position?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the player controlling Gooigi clicks down the joystick twice it recalls Gooigi to Luigi.

Comment: That is the way to do it! I can't believe we missed this!

Answer (score 3):

You could **Exit the room**.

Sure it's not the button combo you are looking for, but while Gooigi is off doing his business you should genuinely have enough time to do your part as Luigi in the room you entered.

If Multiplayer mechanics are anything like the single-player ones, Gooigi should return to Luigi if you leave the room, so just let Luigi clear the room and have a little patience. From what I have seen so far, there are not that many passages where Gooigi is separated from Luigi and can't return anyway.

(Well now I remember the secret room in the shopping mall, but that might be an exception.)

This is not the final answer, but it's a temporary help I guess.

Comment: I will try to look into it when I am home, to try and give an better answer.

Comment: My Gooigi got stuck next to a chest at the bottom of some broken stairs and this was the only solution.  I had to switch to one-player mode first because the camera was focused on the second player

Comment: The scenario was Gooigi dropping through a grill in the floor to another room. I'm not sure if it would be possible to control Luigi during that time, but I'll try if it works when I play again!